# Android: how to launch com.android.documentsui.files.FilesActivity?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to launch this activity https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/008e948/packages/DocumentsUI/src/com/android/documentsui/FilesActivity.java

This is the code I am using

```
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName("com.google.android.documentsui", "com.android.documentsui.files.FilesActivity");
        intent.setComponent(componentName);
        context.startActivity(intent);
```

This throws an ActivityNotFoundException.

I know that package and activity actually exists on my test device, because I see it in the output of `adb shell dumpsys package r`.

Any idea what is wrong and how to launch the activity?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? All of the valid ways to launch that type of activity have public APIs to do so.

Comment: I'd like to open the default file browser app. I found many similar questions on SO, but they all either let the user pick what app to use (I don't want that; I want to use this specific app), or use the file picker to pick a file (which I don't want  either; I just want to open the app and let the user do what they want with the files).